# How autoloading classes works even after uninstalled Composer?

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php

I use local webserver XAMPP + WordPress on Windows 10. PHP v.8.2.0, Composer v.2.5.8.

My actions:

1. Installed Composer globally and some package just for initial test to random directory.
2. Copied "vendor" folder to child theme directory(wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwentythree-child) and
   included autoload.php in functions.php. Made some tests - good, everything works.

Then I deleted almost all files from vendor folder and made some code manipulations. In result, I have folder structure:

```
twentytwentythree-child/
├── vendor/
│   ├── composer/
│   │   └── autoload_real.php
│   └── autoload.php    
├── style.css
└── functions.php
```

functions.php:

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";
```

And this code in autoload_real.php:

```
class ComposerAutoloaderInit205eb07b158c0f9d7b54b8e32a48421e
{
    private static $loader;

    public static function getLoader()
    {
        self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader(\dirname(__DIR__));

        print "<pre>";
        print_r($loader);
        print "</pre>";

        return $loader;
    }
}
```

Without any problems I got the printing result on site page:

```
Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader Object
(
    [vendorDir:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => D:\Prog\Web\XAMPP\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwentythree-child\vendor
    [prefixLengthsPsr4:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [prefixDirsPsr4:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [fallbackDirsPsr4:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [prefixesPsr0:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [fallbackDirsPsr0:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [useIncludePath:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => 
    [classMap:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [classMapAuthoritative:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => 
    [missingClasses:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [apcuPrefix:Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader:private] => 
)
```

There is no ClassLoader.php in my folder structure and other vendor autload files, but this code works, and I don't understand why.

This code doesn't work on other machine, so I thought about Composer cache, tried to clear it with "composer clear-cache" cli command. I tried change local web server.Then I even uninstalled Composer and pointed out to remove all cache too. No effect, printing still works, I see the same output on WordPress page. So if you know, how without almost all vendor files and even Composer program itself, this code still works with no errors, tell me please.

Comment: You don't show any of the code that requires the autoload.php file nor how you create the output, so it is hard to specifically answer your question. However that "almost any" is certainly enough to still load the autoloader class, and as you can see in the output it is just a skeleton, it will do no auto-loading, therefore it certainly works because there is nothing to autoload. Remove the complete vendor/composer folder and the vendor/autoload.php file to really crash it and see it non-working. /E: And: as long as you keep the vendor folder intact, composer is not needed any longer.

Comment: @hakre, requiring autoload.php is in functions.php, it's:
`require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";`

Autoload happens on this line here:
`self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader(\dirname(__DIR__));`.
And in folder structure there is no ClassLoader.php file.

So how without Composer php loads class from nonexistent file? It looks like caching, but where does this caching happen? Maybe Composer is bounded with some php module, which uses data from Composer or something like that?

Comment: Pro-Tip: Make that visible in your question, not in comments. Comments are hard to read, less visible and the clarification is what the question benefits from. And no, there is no secret cache unless you use some form of autoload optimization, IIRC 2B, but that is a) no secret and b) your autoload class is empty, it won't autoload a thing. You perhaps have an additional autoloader, as Composers' autoloader implementation is a good citizen and tries not to take all grounds. C.f. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the reason - some WordPress plugin also uses Composer autoloader with all its files and etc. ClassLoader.php was included by this plugin, i.e. my experimental code works. Big thanks to @hakre for hinting me the right way.

Answer (score -1):

> How autoloading classes works even after uninstalled Composer?

This works because once you have successfully build (installed, by the **composer install** or **composer update** command) the vendor folder, it is self-containing and can run without/independent from Composer only depending on the PHP platform configuration you've used installing it.

The rest is in the vendor folder then, which includes the generated autoloader.

Therefore autoloading classes works even after you uninstalled Composer, because it was independent to it in the first place. This is by the design of Composer, you only use it to *manage* your project dependencies, not to run them.

Comment: What do you mean by "can run without/independent from Composer only depending on the PHP platform" - could you please explain it in little more details and specifically?

Comment: When you run `composer install` Composer takes the configured PHP platform (e.g. which PHP version, which extension versions etc.) and then resolves your projects dependencies against those and "builds" the vendor directory. That's all Composer depends on: a) PHP platform and b) the dependencies of the depenencies. Afterwards this is encoded in the vendor dir and as long as you have the PHP platform runinning, that vendor folder should have the appropriate dependencies (ignoring errors in composer.json misconfigurations within the dependencies, not the common case). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Afterwards, it dumps as well the autoloader into there and then vendor directory is complete. After that point, you don't need Composer as a tool any longer to operate with the vendor directory, e.g. within your scripts and applications: You require vendor/autoload.php and then you have access to all dependencies. That's already all.

Comment: If I run this whole code on other machine like webhosting server, php gives me fatal error, because there are no necessary files(like ClassLoader.php file) in such folder structure. So, what I need to change/do on my localhost to get the same result, i.e. this line `self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader(\dirname(__DIR__));`  must cause the fatal error. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Only an educated guess: Given you run this with your webserver, restart it. PHP Opcache may still have the class. Same if you're using PHP-FPM, also restart the all pools. Otherwise there might be sone more includes you do which load that class from somewhere, you can also check with https://php.net/get_included_files on your box and see if you can spot something that looks fishy.